# Travis-CI not triggering, despite seemingly proper setup

Tags: travis-ci

Can't figure out why my travis build won't trigger. 
Project in question:

https://travis-ci.org/Berserker66/FactorioManager

https://github.com/Berserker66/FactorioManager

There is a .travis.yml and there have been pushes since.

Settings looking fine as well:
[image: Travis Settings]

Comment: Did you enable builds for that repo in travis. (settings/settings a couple of switches.)

Comment: Yes. 15 Characters at least for a comment is stupid.

Comment: https://github.com/mbonaci/mbo-storm/wiki/Integrate-Travis-CI-with-your-GitHub-repo#integrate-your-github-project-with-travis-ci - switch probably not flipped and - service hook not tested from the webinterface.

Comment: Switch is flipped and the service hook is listed on github side.

Answer (score 3):

You can better check the logs as well. As you see in the below screenshot. Goto requests ans see the logs. Then you will be able to find the exact reason.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- I cloned your repository: https://github.com/vlajos/FactorioManager
- I synced my repository in travis.
- I enabled travis to this one, and ticked this option: `Build only if .travis.yml is present`
- Edited the README. (Added a new line)
- And then: https://travis-ci.org/vlajos/FactorioManager

So I think you should turn on this `Build only if .travis.yml is present`
At least I don't see any other difference.